# Unable to open coldfusion Administrator

Tags: coldfusion

when i try opening http://127.0.0.1:8500/test.com
 I get

500 There is no web application configured to service your request There is no web application configured to service your request

when i try opening http://127.0.0.1:8500/CFIDE/

I GET THE same error

Kindly guide me to solution.

Comment: I second divo. This is about as vague as it gets. Have you set up coldfusion server? How about IIS?

Comment: does it  mean I have to reinstall the CF- server?

Comment: I am getting J-run Servelet error on the Mozilla web page.

Comment: What OS?  Can you confirm that ColdFusion is running?

Comment: WINDOWS xp IS THE operation system....

Comment: Open Control Panel -> Services, see if your Adobe ColdFusion is indeed running.  What setup u using? multi-instance? single-instance? with builtin Web Server? apache? pls provide the details.

Comment: I stopped Coldfusion MX server
          Coldfusion ODBC aGENT
          Coldfusion ODBC server

on Administrator tools/Services  


Restarted it and am getting the same error and then getting the same error

Answer (score 2):

It means the server did not fully start. The JRun container started and was able to accept an HTTP Request via its internal webserver port, but then the ColdFusion Server inside JRun was not fully deployed or not deployed at all.

The startup events in /path/to/coldfusion8/runtime/logs/coldfusion-event.log and /path/to/coldfusion8/logs/server.log will contain details about what failed during ColdFusion startup.

You will probably not make sense of the events as they are usually somewhat cryptic.  Please post log contents for further diagnosis.

Comment: That is irrelevant. (And CFMX is not a version.  ColdFusion MX 6, or 6.1, or 7 is a version)